# Ruby / Rails 3: How to create a Date object from a Time object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date, time

Given a `Time` object, say `2011-03-12 21:58:11 +1100`, I would like to get the appropriate `Date` object (`Sat, 12 Mar 2011`).

What is the easiest way to achieve this ?

Rails 3 extensions are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a to_date method for time that can be useful

```
Time.now.to_date
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the 'Time' object [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Time.html#M000320), you can simply use the `to_date` method.

```
date = your_time.to_date
```